# Ionic ion-footer pushed Keyboard up

Tags: ionic-framework, keyboard, ionic4

I have an **ion-footer** in my application in **Ionic**, but I am having a problem where the footer gets pushed up each time the **keyboard** comes out. I have added the:

**Config XML**

```
<preference name="KeyboardResize" value="false" />
<preference name="KeyboardResizeMode" value="ionic" />


<ion-footer class="ion-no-border" slot="fixed">
  <ion-grid class="footer-tab">
    <ion-row justify-content-around>

      <ion-col>
        <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" [routerLink]="['/inicio']">
          <ion-icon color="medium" name="home"></ion-icon> 
        </ion-button>
        Início
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col>
        <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" [routerLink]="['/extrato']"> 
          <ion-icon color="medium" name="list"></ion-icon> 
        </ion-button>
        Abastecimento
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col>
        <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" [routerLink]="['/indicacoes']"> 
          <ion-icon color="medium" name="happy"></ion-icon> 
        </ion-button>
        Indique
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col>
        <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" [routerLink]="['/rede']"> 
          <ion-icon color="success" name="pin"></ion-icon> 
        </ion-button>
        Postos

      </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-footer>
```

CSS

```
  .footer-tab {
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: -webkit-center;
      margin-top: -11px;
      margin-bottom: 2vh;
      color: grey;
    }
```

[Screenshot keyboard pushes to up]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORiA2.jpg

Comment: There is a thing you can achieve is to install keyboard plugin and then check if keyboard is shown then hide footer and if not shown to keep it in view since footer is a main part in page or remove the ion-footer and replace it with normal div and giv it some css to keep at bottom and by that i think it will be solved

Comment: Thanks for your support.It is still not working. ;-)